# Ejabberd: Modify rosters database

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I need to sync the registered users, which is stored in a different database from ejabberd database.

So, Ive decided to manually inject the a roster row to ejabberd `rosterusers` for each related users. Seems that the updated rows only being applied to client's sides after a period of time after the row insertion.

In my case user roster update need to be realtime, is there any configuration or functions to invoke the update after the database row insertion

p/s: I'm using PostgreSQL for database

Comment: Have you tried using export2sql command? This will actually export to a file and you can check the file for rosterusers.

Comment: @LamteiW, thanks for the suggestion, but actually what I try to achieve is, when I inserted a roster item row to ejabberd <code>rosterusers</code> table, the XMPP Client from the system should fetch the latest roster which contains the contact information that i've just inserted.

Currently the latest roster is fetch/updated in certain amount of period.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the only workaround that I've found is to invoke `add_rosteritem` using rest api or `ejabberdctl` after all the new rows insertions being done to   `ejabberd`'s  `rosterusers` table.